# Dimension of the centre of an algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a finite dimensional algebra $A$ with basis say $\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\}$.Suppose if I know the multiplication table of the basis elements, is there any direct way to find the dimension of its center just by the multiplication table?

Is it possible if $A$ is a finite-dimensional C* algebra?

Comment: you mean center as in center of a ring?

Comment: I'm sure he means centre as in the centre of an algebra (presumably over a specific ground field). @Riquelme

Comment: yes. My algebra is over $\mathbb{C}$. The centre is also a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Its dimension.

Comment: Given the data you can generate the matrix of the mapping $\phi:A\to End(A)$ defined by calculating the commutators
$$\phi(X)(Y)=XY-YX$$ with respect to your chosen basis (and the naturally associated basis of linear transformations from $A$ to itself). The kernel of that linear transformation is the center. You can find it with the methods of linear algebra. That matrix is of type $n^2\times n$, so this may not be a pleasant way of going about it with paper&pencil. As an automated process it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am actually in a C* algebra situation. Is there any way to find it with C* algebra techniques? My basis elements are quite complicated In practical I can find the multiplication table. But it can not be done with paper and pencil for sure.